# nuxt : access globals variables stored in the vuex store

Tags: parameters, vuejs2, vuex, getter, nuxt.js

In my NUXT application, i have to share a global array for all my components.
For example, this array contains the labels of the week :

```
export const state = () => ({
  days: [
      { code: '1', label: 'Lundi' },
      { code: '2', label: 'Mardi' },
      { code: '3', label: 'Mercredi' },
      ...
  ]
})

export const getters = {
  getDayLabel (state, dayCode) {
    return state.days[dayCode]
  },
}
```

In my component, i have to display the label of a day. For that, I've written in the template of the component :

```
{{$store.getters['getDayLabel'](dayCode)}}
```

But, I have this error :

> app.js:262 TypeError: _vm.$store.getters.getDayLabel is not a function

I've read in some topics, that a getter function should'nt have parameters ? Is there a better solution ?

Eric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify a new parameter in the store for the getter

For example a getter where you retrieve the information with only the index :

```
 export const getters = {
    getDayLabel: state => index => state.days[index]
}
```

In your template :
`{{$store.getters['getDayLabel'](1).label }} --> output = Mardi`

If you really want to search with a code you can use the filter function :

```
  getDayLabel: state => {
    return dayCode => state.days.filter(c => {
      return c.code === dayCode
    })
  }
```

In your template :
`{{$store.getters['getDayLabel'](2)[0].label }} --> output = Mardi`

More information here [Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/688)

I don't know if this is a good practice or not because I never used it like this before, I always make a filter of the data directly in the component.